TikZ and pgfplots: hide NaN values from a matrix
I'm working on a LaTeX document and using TikZ to create a matrix plot, but I'm encountering an issue. I want to remove the "NaN" text from the cells in the matrix plot and keep those cells blank. Currently, the cells with "NaN" values still show "NaN" as text, which I'd like to avoid.
Here's the code I'm using:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{max height=\textheight, max width=\columnwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
        rgb(0pt)=(0.0,0.0,1.0) % Blue
        rgb(1pt)=(0.0,1.0,1.0) % Cyan
        rgb(2pt)=(0.0,1.0,0.0) % Green
        rgb(3pt)=(1.0,1.0,0.0) % Yellow
        rgb(4pt)=(1.0,0.0,0.0) % Red
      },
      colorbar,
      colorbar style={ylabel={}},
      point meta max=100,
      point meta min=0,
      title={Heatmap con colormap personalizzata},
      x grid style={darkgray176},
      xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
      xtick style={color=black},
      xtick={0,1,2},
      xticklabel style={rotate=90.0},
      xticklabels={A, B, C},
      y dir=reverse,
      y grid style={darkgray176},
      ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5,
      ytick style={color=black},
      ytick={0,1,2},
      yticklabels={A, B, C},
      every axis label/.append style={font=\small},
      tick align=outside,
      tick pos=left,
      every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize, color=black, anchor=center, 
        /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=0
      }
    ]
    \addplot[matrix plot, point meta=explicit, mesh/cols=3, nodes near coords, point meta=explicit] table[meta=Value] {
      x y Value
      0 0 nan
      0 1 60
      0 2 25
      1 0 19
      1 1 nan
      1 2 50
      2 0 40
      2 1 75
      2 2 nan
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Heatmap con matrice 3x3 di numeri casuali}
    \label{fig:Heatmap matrice 3x3}
\end{figure}

And this is what I got:

I would like to keep the cells with "NaN" values exactly blank (white) without any text inside. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
Btw, I already looked at Using nan values in pgfplots but I wasn't able to solve.

Welcome. // Is deleting or overwriting nan an option for you?

Hi, thanks for fast reply. I can avoid inserting "nan" in the table or overwrite it with any specific value. Only thing that matter is the blank cell and no text inside.
Edit: i mean that both movig from 1 1 nan to 1 1 nothing or  1 1 \specificcommand are an option for me

The problem arises from the mesh-surface you use, which expects 3 columns of data. When one is missing, it doesn't compile, as data are needed for calculations. // If you search for NaN in the pgfplots-manual, there are several alternatives (using coordinates) to create such a plot; looking for colorbar lets you influence the bar itself, while nan simply isnt't plotted; you could even substitute a 0 for white etc. // Visually speaking, communicating "NaN" is different from presenting a white area ... so why not adopting that implementation?

You can test if a number is NaN with \pgfmathfloatifflags, using the flag 3 (from the manual of the TikZ/fpu library). Define a custom macro, like
\NewDocumentCommand{\printmynumber}{ m }
{%
  \pgfmathfloatifflags{#1}{3}
  {}% NaN
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}% not NaN
}

to print a number, except if it is flagged as NaN.
Then, as nodes near coords means nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta (from the pgfplots manual), replace \pgfmathprintnumber with the custom macro \printmynumber with
nodes near coords=\printmynumber\pgfplotspointmeta

Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printmynumber}{ m }
{%
  \pgfmathfloatifflags{#1}{3}
  {}% NaN
  {\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}% not NaN
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
        rgb(0pt)=(0.0,0.0,1.0) % Blue
        rgb(1pt)=(0.0,1.0,1.0) % Cyan
        rgb(2pt)=(0.0,1.0,0.0) % Green
        rgb(3pt)=(1.0,1.0,0.0) % Yellow
        rgb(4pt)=(1.0,0.0,0.0) % Red
      },
      colorbar,
      colorbar style={ylabel={}},
      point meta max=100,
      point meta min=0,
      title={Heatmap con colormap personalizzata},
      x grid style={darkgray176},
      xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
      xtick style={color=black},
      xtick={0,1,2},
      xticklabel style={rotate=90.0},
      xticklabels={A, B, C},
      y dir=reverse,
      y grid style={darkgray176},
      ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5,
      ytick style={color=black},
      ytick={0,1,2},
      yticklabels={A, B, C},
      every axis label/.append style={font=\small},
      tick align=outside,
      tick pos=left,
      every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize, color=black, anchor=center,
        /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=0
      }
    ]
    \addplot[%
      matrix plot,
      point meta=explicit,
      mesh/cols=3,
      nodes near coords=\printmynumber\pgfplotspointmeta,
      point meta=explicit
    ] table[meta=Value] {
      x y Value
      0 0 nan
      0 1 60
      0 2 25
      1 0 19
      1 1 nan
      1 2 50
      2 0 40
      2 1 75
      2 2 nan
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Ah, yes, that's much better and kitten-safe

don't use this: use @jlab's answer, which is much better!
I'm leaving this here as an example on how not to do this thing ;-)
This is a bit of a hack (← read "an awful hack prone to fail in one million different ways as soon as somebody legitimately changes the pgf code, to crash your computer, and to kill your kittens"-type of code).
You can change the way pgfmath represents a NaN. Unfortunately, there is no global variable to do this, so we need to patch (ach!) inner code. Add to the preamble:
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\myhackNaNout{NaN}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl}
    {\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{\hbox{NaN}}{}}
    {\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{\hbox{\myhackNaNout}}{}}
    {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

This will change the fixed string "NaN" to a macro \myhackNaNout, set to the same value, which hopefully does not change anything more. Again, that can fail in some part of pgf code I do not understand, so...
Then, in your axis env, set
\renewcommand\myhackNaNout{~}

the most locally scoped you can, and cross fingers. Full MWE with output following (please, next time, post a complete MWE, not a snippet).
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand\myhackNaNout{NaN}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl}
    {\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{\hbox{NaN}}{}}
    {\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{\hbox{\myhackNaNout}}{}}
    {}{\FAIL}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
     \begin{axis}[
      colormap={mymap}{[1pt]
        rgb(0pt)=(0.0,0.0,1.0) % Blue
        rgb(1pt)=(0.0,1.0,1.0) % Cyan
        rgb(2pt)=(0.0,1.0,0.0) % Green
        rgb(3pt)=(1.0,1.0,0.0) % Yellow
        rgb(4pt)=(1.0,0.0,0.0) % Red
      },
      colorbar,
      colorbar style={ylabel={}},
      point meta max=100,
      point meta min=0,
      title={Heatmap con colormap personalizzata},
      x grid style={darkgray176},
      xmin=-0.5, xmax=2.5,
      xtick style={color=black},
      xtick={0,1,2},
      xticklabel style={rotate=90.0},
      xticklabels={A, B, C},
      y dir=reverse,
      y grid style={darkgray176},
      ymin=-0.5, ymax=2.5,
      ytick style={color=black},
      ytick={0,1,2},
      yticklabels={A, B, C},
      every axis label/.append style={font=\small},
      tick align=outside,
      tick pos=left,
      every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize, color=black, anchor=center, 
        /pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=0
      }
    ]
    \renewcommand\myhackNaNout{~}
    \addplot[matrix plot, mesh/cols=3, nodes near coords, point meta=explicit,
        ] table[meta=Value] {
      x y Value
      0 0 nan
      0 1 60
      0 2 25
      1 0 19
      1 1 nan
      1 2 50
      2 0 40
      2 1 75
      2 2 nan
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



If somebody knows how to check for NaN in a pgfmath expression, maybe this could be done in a clean way using point meta=<expression>... https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-meta#pgfplots/point_meta
